# Multiple JS Show/Hide

Tags: javascript, show-hide, multiple-instances

I have a show/hide functionality for the Video and FAQ section on the following test page: [code]http://63.246.25.145/surety-bonds/contract-bonds/performance_bond.htm[/code]

I believe my code should show 5 FAQs and 3 videos, but it is displaying 3 FAQS and 3 Videos.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't expect people to go through all the JavaScript/HTML you've written. Isolate the problematic piece of code and copy it here.

Comment: Please put the relevant portions of your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are showing 5 'li' elements, but the answers are 'li' elements as well. To display 5 questions, you need to show the first 10 list items.

```
if(f.children("li").size()<=10)
    return;
```

Comment: Better yet, filter it to items with the class `question`

Comment: LOL. I took pity on him  :)

Comment: Thanks SteveP!  That was a dumb move on my part.  I don't know JS (obviously), only PHP so this one may have taken forever without you, but is clear now.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Dark Falcon, this isn't my code.  I'm just modifying someone else's and I don't know JS.  Can you clarify your suggestion further for me?  Thanks in advance.  It is greatly appreciated.